# Density function of a negative random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

Let $X$ be an independent random variable uniformly distributed in $(0, 1)$

Hence I have $f_X(x)=\mathbb{1}_{(0,1)}(x)$, but what can I say about $f_{-X}(x)$?

Sorry, maybe it's a trivial question, but I never worked with negative variables. Any help/hint?

Is $f_{-X}(x)=\mathbb{1}_{(0,1)}(-x)=f_X(-x)$?

Comment: Yes.   You are getting bog downed by notation.  To simplify in plain English:  If $X$ is uniformly distributed in $(0,1)$, then $-X$ is uniformly distributed in $(-1,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** We just introduced a new random variable

$$Y=-X,$$
ditributed in $(-1,0)$, so we can try to understand its cdf by using our understanding of $X$:
$$F_Y(y)= P(Y \leq y) = P(X\geq -y) = 1- F_X(-y). $$

We can then differentiate to get the pdf of $Y$.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the hint! Thus, differentiating and rewriting with $-X=Y, y=x$, we find that $f_{-X}(x)=-f_X(-x)$ right?

Comment: Nope. :) $f_Y(y)=F_Y'(y) = (1- F_X(-y))'=-F'_X(-y)(-y)'= F'_X(-y) = f_X(-y)$